# Writing On the Board vs. Showing Slides

Tags: teaching, professorship, presentation

There is a new trend on some Universities (in engineering and science majors), that professors show lecture slides over a video projector on the screen instead of writing on the chalkboard. They enter the hall, stay two hours totally passive before the students and read the slides aloud without explaining it. I even have had a mathematics course, in which the professor read the slides like a textbook without explaining them on the board or working examples.

Are you also affected? Which method do you think is more effective? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each? (I myself believe the chalkboard is much more effective.)

Comment: Closely related question: [In teaching, what are the advantages of using slides over doing board work?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/29322/546)

Comment: To me, this question sounds like "What is better? Your crop fields getting flooded completely or a little drought on your field?" - that's a no-brainer, and also not a good question to ask, as the answer doesn't tell you anything about what is best.

Comment: As currently written your question is a very bad fit for this site. "Are you also affected" is a poll. "What do you think is more effective" is opinion-based, though it *could* maybe be made more objective with a request for references. Also, you seem to have formed a strong opinion anyway, and as such I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Also, I like that you think this to be a "new trend". I entered university in 2002, and I can count on one hand the lecturers that used chalkboard rather than pre-prepared slides (powerpoint or handwritten prepared).

Comment: @xLeitix I do have an opinion on it, but it does not mean that I am totally right. Everybody sees that from his point of view and having different views helps to see those angles that you might have missed and eventually build up a better big picture of the subject. That is one of the goals of such Forums. People do not ask questions because they do not have an opinion on the subject but because they want to to know other people's views on that matter.

Comment: Voting to close this question because if stripped from the polls it would be a duplicate.

Comment: @Infinity Unfortunately gathering a lot of opinions is not how Stack Exchange works. Specifically, this is *not* "one of the goals of" *this specific* forum, even though your statement is certainly true for forums in general.

Comment: @Infinity: [Stack Exchange is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/255554). And while Stack Exchange may be helpful for forming educated opinions, it is not for just asking for opinions.

Answer (score 7):

What you describe is not teaching with slides, it is teaching *very badly* with slides.  A teacher can teach very badly with the board too: as an undergraduate, I had one mathematics professor who only mumbled inaudibly while either facing at an oblique angle to the class or else while writing small unintelligible letters on the chalkboard in a descending arc.

Slides can be an excellent teaching tool, in that they allow a professor to show images, data, illustrations, and other things that cannot be readily drawn by hand.  I find that their main disadvantage is that they are fixed before the class, and thus cannot be readily adjusted or corrected to track the interaction with students on the fly.  Conversely, working on the board can be more interactive, but must remain much simpler, which can be either a good or a bad thing, depending on content.